# rake aborted! Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined mixin 'font-face'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass, compass-sass

here is my little problem. 
I created a website with ruby on rails 4 and I made a bit of sass and css when making a push on heroku he said

`rake aborted Sass :: SyntaxError: Undefined mixin 'font-face'`

and yet I see what's missing.

here is my file _font.sass

```
+font-face("logo", font-files("Bira_PERSONAL_USE_ONLY.ttf"))
=logo
 font-family: "logo"
```

Here is called or _header.sass

```
.logo
  +logo
  background-color: $green
  width: 187px
  float: left
  text-align: center
  color: $white
  font-size: 36px
  padding: 23px 0px 27px 0px
  text-decoration: none
```

and here is the file there my sass import main.css.sass

```
@import "compass"
@import "compass/reset"
@import "compass/css3"

@import "base/color"
@import "base/font"
@import "layouts/header"
@import "modules/nav"
```

css to work I had to add a file to the `assets.rb` initiallizers directory for my css works

`file assets.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( main.css )
```

here layouts whit css

```
!!!
%html
  %head
   %title FrenchDev
   = stylesheet_link_tag    'main', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
   = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
   = csrf_meta_tags
 %body
  %header
   .container
     %a.logo{href:"/"}
       test

     %nav
       %ul
         %li Home
         %li Projet
         %li Tutoriel
         %li Contact
 = yield
```

I do not see what is wrong

thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are missing this line:

```
@import "compass/css3/font-face"
```

It  should be placed before this line:

```
+font-face("logo", font-files("Bira_PERSONAL_USE_ONLY.ttf"))
```

Comment: its not my fault but still I feel that it is not yet compass that local market so I do not understand

Comment: Are you importing the mixin before you use it?